# sequelize auto update updatedAt error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to update the accesstoken of tokens[0] like this,

```
tokens[0].accesstoken = newTokenObj.accesstoken;
tokens[0].save();
```

I got this:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: string violation: updatedAt cannot be an array or an object
```

I only change the accesstoken, and updatedAt timestamp should be updated by Sequelize. Why this error happened?

this is tokens[0],the only element in tokens

```
accesstoken {
  dataValues:
   { id: 1,
     accesstoken: '10_PRQpRztWb1ZL3hgLwLhaftmputRbePB39VxIJ-sCdFfzIPGjWEOX_DYV_Y18MOHHpuRmWDrTBVK7twkas_-KknBjo4vo1fiy-mlUIt_dgLMGkqjPFYCXNhuxZwBanbu27kan9IFfvkOOS1zABPKdADAJXS',
     updatedAt: 2018-05-21T01:12:25.000Z,
     createdAt: 2018-05-21T15:12:08.000Z },
  _previousDataValues:
   { id: 1,
     accesstoken: '10_ZMeWuvau9H3ATIGC3g_xoWRHOOpkHietdHommGIQ4Ms5Wo_jZQVy_mv0fG6hbA8QBeSWlBHnlP6bWEnwy_rpCAajYhlGtlZLcgGLMvv1ZRBOCW4JGddmPv19quwKoSYazmX0wUEteuQei0lvXUEfABATQA',
     updatedAt: 2018-05-21T01:12:25.000Z,
     createdAt: 2018-05-21T15:12:08.000Z },
  _changed: { accesstoken: true },
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     underscoredAll: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: { id: 1 },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: [],
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'accesstokens', singular: 'accesstoken' },
     omitNull: false,
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [Object],
        queryInterface: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [Object],
        connectionManager: [Object],
        importCache: {},
        test: [Object] },
     hooks: {},
     uniqueKeys: {} },
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     raw: true,
     attributes: [ 'id', 'accesstoken', 'updatedAt', 'createdAt' ] },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
```

When I use update, I got the same error

```
tokens[0].update({
    accesstoken:newTokenObj.accesstoken
});
```

So I can only set validate:false to pass the validate step

Comment: Please provide more info. Can you `console.log` your `token` and `token[0]`

Comment: @AbhinavD  I provide the tokens[0] just now, and it's the only element in  tokens

Comment: This code looks alright to me. Can you post the update command  ran by Sequelize

Comment: @AbhinavD, the update command got the same error, so I can only set validate:false to pass the validate step(⊙︿⊙)

Comment: This is really weird. One last try would be to post the query generated by sequelize when trying to update